# Gatsby + Markdown: How to get data from a specific markdown file into a single page?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby, and making my best to learn it (along with React, in which I have no prior knowledge either). I'd like to create a single page getting data from one or several markdown files.

For now I'm testing it out with just Gatsby, in order to later reproduce that technique with Netlify CMS markdown files (and be able to update the page texts with Netlify CMS admin panel).
So far, I've managed to add markdown pages to Gatsby, thanks to this [tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/). But this method only creates dynamic pages, which is far more complex than what I need.

Is there a simple way to import one specific markdown file, let's say src/markdowns/hero-texts.md, in (let's also say) pages/index.js, and then call data with their frontmatter tags, in the cleanest way as possible?

I've tried countless researches on Google just to find which plugin or coding term would handle that, without success. I totally get some of the explanations above may be full of technical misunderstandings, sorry for that...

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. Still have to dive deeper into it, though.

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Still learning sorry ^^, I should have done this months before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a markdown file called `hero-texts.md` and you want to be able to query its frontmatter content.

Install the plugins `gatsby-transformer-remark` and `gatsby-source-filesystem` and setup the `gatsby-source-filesystem` options to find your markdown files.

---

```
// gatsby-config.js

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
              name: `markdown`,
              path: `${__dirname}/src/markdowns/`
            }
        },
        `gatsby-transformer-remark`
    ]
}
```

You could make a graphql page query like this inside `index.js` (then the result of the query is automatically added to your index component under `props.data`)

```
// src/pages/index.js

import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

const IndexPage = ({data}) => {
  return (
  <>
    <p>{data.markdownRemark.frontmatter.author}</p>
    <p>{data.markdownRemark.frontmatter.date}</p>
    <p>{data.markdownRemark.frontmatter.title}</p>
  </>
)}

export default IndexPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexPageQuery {
    markdownRemark(fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/hero-texts.md/" }) {
      frontmatter {
        author
        date
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

---

It will perform the graphql query at build time, and add the result of the query to the `data` prop of the `IndexPage` page component.

So in effect, pulling in all the frontmatter fields from a markdown file that looked like this.

```
// src/markdowns/hero-texts.md

---
title: "Gatsby + Markdown: How to simply get data from a specific markdown in a single page?"
author: Florent Despinoy
date: 2019-08-06
---

# This is my markdown post

The content of this markdown file would not be queried by pageQuery (only the frontmatter would)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly. If this method is the only one for that purpose, I guess one cannot query several markdown files a .js? Now I'll try to replicate this method with Netlify CMS!

Comment: Yes you can. You can use `allMarkdownRemark` to query all of your markdown pages.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-six/#create-a-list-of-your-sites-markdown-files-in-srcpagesindexjs

Comment: Also, remember to open up your `graphql` explorer and check out what is available for you to query.

Comment: How is value of pageQuery getting passed into the IndexPage function? It's not being referenced that I can see here. I get that it works, but not why / how it works. I don't like that feeling :)

Comment: That's all gatsby. Check the docs https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/

Comment: what if we want to query data for a dynamically generated page (in its template)? how would you then get the name of the ".md" file?