# Accessing a markdown file into a component in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am looking to include content inside .md file into a component in gatsby, but not sure what the query should be (finding this very confusing).

**gatsby-config.js**

```js
[
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    options: {
      name: `markdown`,
      path: `${__dirname}/src/markdowns`,
    },
  },
  `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
]
```

**experience.md**

```markdown
---
title: "Gatsby + Markdown: How to simply get data from a specific markdown in a single page?"
author: Florent Despinoy
date: 2019-08-06
---
```

The queries tried:

**Note**: experience.md is infact inside - src/markdowns/experience.md

```js
query IndexPageQuery {
  markdownRemark(fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/experience.md/" }) {
    // here fileAbsolutePath is undefined
    frontmatter {
      author
      date
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Tried to follow other answers but non of them seem to work ([One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383019))